# List of dataframes, how can I group every nth element?

Tags: r, list, grouping

Let's say I have a list of dataframes called `old_list`:

```
#old_list will be a list of length 10

#Create vectors for the dfs (there's probably a concise way to do this). 

old_list<-list(rnorm(10),rnorm(10),rnorm(10),rnorm(10),rnorm(10),rnorm(10),
               rnorm(10),rnorm(10),rnorm(10),rnorm(10))

#Turn old_list into a df; add a second column
library('dplyr')

old_list<-lapply(old_list,function(x) as.data.frame(x)%>%mutate(mu=1))
```

Ok, now `old_list` looks something like this:

```
   [[1]]
             x mu
1  -0.47734743  1
2   0.28986887  1
3   0.02933248  1
4  -2.15761840  1
5   0.32944305  1
6   0.33237442  1
7  -0.48621491  1
8  -0.61504793  1
9  -1.45353709  1
10 -1.22628027  1

[[2]]
             x mu
1   0.10329026  1
2  -0.43502662  1
3   0.87865194  1
4  -0.37628634  1
5   0.06234334  1
6   0.35441583  1
7   0.46176186  1
8   1.98786158  1
9   1.81183387  1
10  2.18143130  1 .... up to the 10th element
```

I want to go about grouping every nth df in `old_list` into a new list called `new_list`. Let's say I want to group every second df. `new_list`should then have a list of length 5 where every element should contain 2 dfs. I've tried code like this:

```
new_list<-list()
for (i in 1:seq(1,length(old_list),2)){
  new_list[[i]]<-list(old_list[i:i+1])
  }
```

But this doesn't 'group' the 1st and 2nd, 3rd and 4th, 5th and 6th... dfs from `old_list` like I'd like. Any tips?

This is what the first element of `new_list` should look like (I didn't set a seed so ignore the different values of rnorm(10):

```
list(c(old_list[1],old_list[2]))
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
             x mu
1   0.56877414  1
2  -2.35897500  1
3   1.16982547  1
4  -0.36609697  1
5   0.53758988  1
6  -1.05709000  1
7  -1.15997033  1
8  -0.07746139  1
9  -0.55179839  1
10 -0.11192844  1

[[1]][[2]]
             x mu
1   0.34540644  1
2  -0.14567340  1
3  -0.56627562  1
4   0.22785077  1
5  -1.73692747  1
6  -1.03707293  1
7  -0.32093204  1
8   0.09449727  1
9   0.41419075  1
10 -0.17093046  1
```

Comment: whats is "every second df" ? there are 10 dfs and only one second df as I understand

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper I added an example of what my output should look like

Comment: old list is not length 10 but length 11 btw :)

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Ah thanks, I'll change that. That's what I get for copy pasting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we need to split up the `list` and nest elements based on 'n', we use `gl` to create a grouping variable, `split` up the 'old_list' and convert it to a `tibble`

```
library(tidyverse)
n <- 2
map2(list(old_list), length(old_list),
       ~split(.x, as.integer(gl(.y, n, .y)))) %>% 
      modify_depth(3, ~tibble(x = ., mu = 1))
```

---

Or may be this

```
n <- 2
res <- lapply(split(old_list, as.integer(gl(length(old_list), n, 
          length(old_list)))), function(x) 
          lapply(x, function(y) data.frame(x= y, mu = 1)))

res[1]
#$`1`
#$`1`[[1]]
#             x mu
#1   1.11696564  1
#2  -0.32362765  1
#3   0.07355866  1
#4   0.97178378  1
#5   0.55000016  1
#6   0.34958254  1
#7   1.32894403  1
#8  -1.02388909  1
#9   0.48285111  1
#10 -0.55077723  1

#$`1`[[2]]
#            x mu
#1  -0.4506403  1
#2   0.8701737  1
#3   3.3360928  1
#4   1.4608549  1
#5   1.1038983  1
#6   2.3979434  1
#7   0.1652383  1
#8   0.2294786  1
#9   0.2031739  1
#10 -0.4322401  1
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is what I'm after. I added some example output of what I'd like to accomplish. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting this error message: Error: Each variable must be a 1d atomic vector or list.
Problem variables: '.'

Comment: @lecreprays Thanks, I was thinking in another direction with the first option.  will update it

Answer (score 2):

Does that work ?

```
n=2;
starts <- seq(1,length(old_list),n)
ends   <- unique(c(seq(n,length(old_list),n),length(old_list)))
res <- Map(function(x,y){old_list[x:y]},starts,ends)
length(res)  # 6
lengths(res) # [1] 2 2 2 2 2 1
```

Comment: Wow, this is really nice code. Thanks. I'll have to read about purrr and Map (if I could pick two answers I would!).

Comment: this is base R :), `Map` with a capital, `purr:map` works in a similar way, with arguments in a different order

Comment: Cool. When would you use Map vs. an anonymous function within lapply?

Comment: `Map` accepts 2 parallel arguments that you iterate through, here `starts` and `ends`, `lapply` takes only one, though it can be a list of different items. In general if you're going to do something weird with `apply` or `lapply` it's good to think about `Map` `purr::map`, `purr::map2`, `purr::pmap`

Comment: and I said something wrong in my previous comment, `Map` is similar to `purrr::map2`, `lapply` is similar to `purrr:map`